# Put custom control Strings into application resource

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, localization

I have a custom winforms control (inherits from Component) that has some strings displayed to the user.

How can I make these strings accessible so the user of the component can customize them, and - if he wants - easily put them into a resource for localization?

I thought of exposing them as browsable properties so they can be customized, but I am not sure if this is the "right thing to do".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make them [Localizable(true)] properties and everything is taken care of.

Note that [Browsable(true)] is the default.